# How to classify content and actions?

Tags: labels, color-combination

How can I classify a type of action or content? Such as distinguishing two actions and content, the Customer and the Seller.

Would the use of colours be convenient? Example:

- **Blue** buttons indicate actions a customer would take, blue icons (next
  to content) refers to content that will interest a **customer**.
- **Red** buttons indicate actions a seller would take, red icons (next to
  content) refers to content that will interest a **seller**.

Are there better ways to do this? Such as only icons (inside buttons & next to content), which can be alot more memorable depending on the icon.

If using colors do they have to be opposites? For example this [colour palette](http://www.colourlovers.com/palette/871636/A_Dream_in_Color) do not provides colours that are distinguishable such as blue and red and is one of the issues I am facing...

The users needs to distinguish the kind of content and action. On this platform the user is given the ability to buy and sell, such as in Ebay.

Comment: Who needs to be able to distinguish these actions? Why are they in the same screen in the first place?

Comment: even if u use color how would they know which color is for whom?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than distinguish actions on a page, instead distinguish the page itself. It would be very odd to have actions where you can do both types of interaction on a single page. Create a visually distinct style between Sellers and Buyers. If you incorporate different color schemes in these two styles (such as Orange for Buyers, and Blue for Sellers) then on the *very rare* pages that incorporate actions for both types of user, you might use those colors as indicators. Which colors you choose is mostly a design issue, not UX; but whatever you choose as the colors that theme pages for the two types of users, buttons should match that theme.